# How do I add exclusion keywords and network search paramters using google-api-ads-ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, google-ads-api

I am trying to figure out how to add a couple of additional search parameters to the request using the [adwords api ruby gem](https://github.com/googleads/google-api-ads-ruby). Here's the example I'm trying to work with. Unfortunately the documentation lacks any instruction on how to add the additional params and Google's API docs are cryptic.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# Encoding: utf-8
#
# Author:: api.dklimkin@gmail.com (Danial Klimkin)
#
# Copyright:: Copyright 2011, Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#
# License:: Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
#           you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
#           You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#           http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#           Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#           distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#           WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
#           implied.
#           See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#           limitations under the License.
#
# This example retrieves keywords that are related to a given keyword.
#
# Tags: TargetingIdeaService.get

require 'adwords_api'
require 'json'

def get_keyword_ideas(_keywords)
  # AdwordsApi::Api will read a config file from ENV['HOME']/adwords_api.yml
  # when called without parameters.
  adwords = AdwordsApi::Api.new

  # To enable logging of SOAP requests, set the log_level value to 'DEBUG' in
  # the configuration file or provide your own logger:
  # adwords.logger = Logger.new('adwords_xml.log')

  targeting_idea_srv = adwords.service(:TargetingIdeaService, API_VERSION)

  # Construct selector object.
  selector = {
    :idea_type => 'KEYWORD',
    :request_type => 'STATS', # 'IDEAS',
    :requested_attribute_types =>
        ['KEYWORD_TEXT', 'SEARCH_VOLUME', 'TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES', 'COMPETITION', 'AVERAGE_CPC'],
    :search_parameters => [
      {
        # The 'xsi_type' field allows you to specify the xsi:type of the object
        # being created. It's only necessary when you must provide an explicit
        # type that the client library can't infer.
        :xsi_type => 'RelatedToQuerySearchParameter',
        :queries => _keywords
      },
      {
        # Language setting (optional).
        # The ID can be found in the documentation:
        #  https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/languagecodes
        # Only one LanguageSearchParameter is allowed per request.
        :xsi_type => 'LanguageSearchParameter',
        :languages => [{:id => 1000}]
      },
      {
        :xsi_type => 'LocationSearchParameter',
        :locations => [{:id => 21177}] # Utah
      }
    ],
    :paging => {
      :start_index => 0,
      :number_results => PAGE_SIZE
    }
  }

  # Define initial values.
  offset = 0
  results = []

  begin
    # Perform request.
    page = targeting_idea_srv.get(selector)
    results += page[:entries] if page and page[:entries]

    # Prepare next page request.
    offset += PAGE_SIZE
    selector[:paging][:start_index] = offset
  end while offset < page[:total_num_entries]

  puts results.to_json

  # Display results.
  results.each do |result|
    data = result[:data]
    keyword = data['KEYWORD_TEXT'][:value]
    puts "----------------\nFound keyword with text '%s'" % keyword
    targeted_monthly_searches = data['TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES'][:value]
    if targeted_monthly_searches
      puts "\tWith targeted monthly searches: #{targeted_monthly_searches.to_json}"
    end
    average_monthly_searches = data['SEARCH_VOLUME'][:value]
    if average_monthly_searches
      puts "\tand average monthly search volume: %d" % average_monthly_searches
    end
  end
  # puts "Total keywords related to '%s': %d." % [keyword_text, results.length]
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  API_VERSION = :v201502
  PAGE_SIZE = 100

  begin
    keywords = [
      'car insurance logan utah',
      'logan utah insurance',
      'logan insurance',
      'insurance logan utah',
      'insurance logan',
      'logan ut insurance',
      'north logan ut insurance',
      'car insurance logan',
      'car insurance logan ut',
      'insurance logan ut',
      'logan car insurance',
      'nibley insurance'
    ]
    get_keyword_ideas(keywords)

  # Authorization error.
  rescue AdsCommon::Errors::OAuth2VerificationRequired => e
    puts "Authorization credentials are not valid. Edit adwords_api.yml for " +
        "OAuth2 client ID and secret and run misc/setup_oauth2.rb example " +
        "to retrieve and store OAuth2 tokens."
    puts "See this wiki page for more details:\n\n  " +
        'http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ads-ruby/wiki/OAuth2'

  # HTTP errors.
  rescue AdsCommon::Errors::HttpError => e
    puts "HTTP Error: %s" % e

  # API errors.
  rescue AdwordsApi::Errors::ApiException => e
    puts "Message: %s" % e.message
    puts 'Errors:'
    e.errors.each_with_index do |error, index|
      puts "\tError [%d]:" % (index + 1)
      error.each do |field, value|
        puts "\t\t%s: %s" % [field, value]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Here's the corrected selector hash:

```
selector = {
  :idea_type => 'KEYWORD',
  :request_type => 'STATS', # 'IDEAS',
  :requested_attribute_types =>
      ['KEYWORD_TEXT', 'SEARCH_VOLUME', 'TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES', 'COMPETITION', 'AVERAGE_CPC'],
  :search_parameters => [
    {
      # The 'xsi_type' field allows you to specify the xsi:type of the object
      # being created. It's only necessary when you must provide an explicit
      # type that the client library can't infer.
      :xsi_type => 'RelatedToQuerySearchParameter',
      :queries => _keywords
    },
    {
      # Language setting (optional).
      # The ID can be found in the documentation:
      #  https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/languagecodes
      # Only one LanguageSearchParameter is allowed per request.
      :xsi_type => 'LanguageSearchParameter',
      :languages => [{:id => 1000}]
    },
    {
      :xsi_type => 'LocationSearchParameter',
      :locations => [{:id => 21177}] # Utah
    },
    {
      :xsi_type => 'NetworkSearchParameter',
      :network_setting => {
        :target_google_search => true,
        :target_search_network => false,
        :target_content_network => false
      }
    },
    {
      :xsi_type => 'ExcludedKeywordSearchParameter',
      :keywords => [
        {text: 'uk', match_type: 'BROAD'},
        {text: 'canada', match_type: 'BROAD'}
      ]
    },
  ],
  :paging => {
    :start_index => 0,
    :number_results => PAGE_SIZE
  }
}
```